# getting an error not related to form validation

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to inject the id (brand_id) from the previous website into a form, due to the fact that the object i am trying to create on the DB depends on that foreignkey relationship. Here's the code

```
from brand.models import Brand
from .models import Campaign
from .forms import CampaignForm
# Create your views here.

def campaign_create(request):
   previous_website = request.META['HTTP_REFERER']
   brand_id = int(previous_website.rsplit('/', 1)[-1])
   print(brand_id)
   brand_object = Brand.objects.get(id=brand_id)

   # if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
   #     raise Http404

   title = "Create Campaign"
   form = CampaignForm(request.POST or None)

    # check whether it's valid:

   if form.is_valid(): #Checking that form is valid
        instance = form.save(commit=False) # saving the form as an instance object
        instance.user = request.user
        instance.brand = brand_object #adding the brand object
        instance.save() # saving in the database

        # redirect to a new URL:

        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
     context = {
    "form": form,
    "title": title,
    }

   return render(request, "campaign_form.html", context)
```

Outside the code (in shell), this works flawlessly, the issue is when I try to submit the code, although I get the correct ID number (prints the correct value in log) and i get the correct brand_object, I am getting a ValueError

ValueError at /dashboard/campaign/create/
invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

since the meta value changes to the current website before submitting the form (new previous_website is now the current website). How can I make it so that I can get the META value before it changes, or what other methods can I use in order to get the brand object this object creation depends on without having it change dynamically?

My flow is:

- Create brand --> localhost:/dashboard/brand/create
- Redirect to that brand after brand creation --> localhost:/dashboard/brand/detail/(brand_id)
- Create campaign (that is tied to a brand) localhost:/dashboard/campaign/create

Brand and Campaign are apps that are connected as a ForeignKey (One brand can have multiple campaings but one campaign can't have more than one brand)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the `brand_id` on `campaign_create`'s url

```
url(r'^dashboard/campaign/create/(?P<brand_id>[0-9]+)/', views.campaign_create),
```

and in the view use [get_object_or_404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) function:

```
def campaign_create(request, brand_id):
    brand_object = get_object_or_404(Brand, pk=brand_id)
    # ...
```